# changing app language using buttons in runtime

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change the application language using two buttons, First I used this code in this link : https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift/blob/master/Sources/Localize.swift
Localize.swift and placed it in my project , 
And here is the code of the table view controller that has two buttons and two lables :

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewVontroller: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var arabicChanger: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var englishChanger: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    populateValues()

}



@IBAction func englishChanger(sender: AnyObject) {

    Localize.setCurrentLanguage("en")
}



@IBAction func arabicChanger(sender: AnyObject) {

   Localize.setCurrentLanguage("ar")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}



func populateValues(){

    firstLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("PETRA",comment: "")

    secondLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("AMMAN",comment: "")

}
}
```

But when I run it and press any of the buttons nothing changes. Even though localization works just fine as I have a Strings files for both languages and when changing language from the system it works, but it doesn't when the buttons are pressed.

Comment: You may be changing the localization, but perhaps that doesn't magically cause your _interface_ to change.

Comment: The documentation mentions the `LCLLanguageChangeNotification` notification for responding to language change events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me first quote what the library's github information page says

> To update the UI in the viewcontroller where a language change can
>   take place, observe LCLLanguageChangeNotification :

you have to add an observer for this to change, to know how an observer works,get your self familiar with [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/)

by the way, I don't recommend to use a third party library in this case, just go with the standards for simple tasks, try using the default `NSLocalizedString` localization, it's great !

Comment: you are welcome our sister :) , if you run into any problem let us know, we will always be happy to help.